# Getting posts insight data from Facebook API / FQL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

The Facebook insights dashboard has a grid that shows all recent posts along with reach/engagement/virality metrics. How can one pull this type of post data from Facebook's graph API or FQL?

[image: Facebook insights dashboard]